# Ignore some BBCodes in REGEX

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex and I want to extract the text including [b].
How can I ignore the [b], [i] and [u]

```
~id="schedule-text".*?]([^[]*)~is

[cs_text id="schedule-text" class="cs-ta-center"]OPEN [b]HOUSE[/b]  Sunday, 12/4 from 2-4pm Additional showings by appointment[/cs_text]
```

https://regex101.com/r/ukHENx/1

**Expected output:**

```
OPEN [b]HOUSE[/b]  Sunday, 12/4 from 2-4pm Additional showings by appointment
```

Comment: I cant use str_replace because I need to store [b] in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this one will be helpful.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ukHENx/2)

**Regex:** `id="schedule-text".*?]\K.*?(?=\[/cs)`

> **1.** `id="schedule-text".*?]` this will match `id="schedule-text"` and till the next occurrence of `]`
>
> **2.** `\K` this will reset the whole match
>
> **3.** `.*?(?=\[/cs)` this will match all and positive look ahead for `[/cs`